# Override system-wide keyboard shortcuts in vs-code

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

[Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcut Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KYc1.png)

[VSC Keyboard Shortcut Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKWH2.png)

I currently have the command alt+w set to close the active window in the global shortcut settings. However, when VSC is focused I would like alt+w to override the system shortcut and close the current editor. Right now it still closes the entire VSC window.